# Nuget Package does not copy content to output directory

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

I'm using a nuspec file to build the package BOS.Shell and reference it from the UI.Warehouse project.

As can be seen, the target is a class library Package Reference project on Framework 4.7.2.

When I build the project I expect the CONTENT FILES to be copied to the output directory, but it does not ?

The binary files (dll's) works as expected, it is the other (content) files that is the issue.

So in other words, I need to deploy non binary files in the OUTPUT directory of the target project of my NuGet package, when the target project is a .net FRAMEWORK class library using Package Reference.

NuGet Version: 5.8.0.6930

[image]
[image]

Comment: Instead, use this `<file src=".bin\net472\Csla.xml" target="contentFiles\any\net472\Csla.xml"/>` under nuspec file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is under `<file src=".bin\net472\Csla.xml" target="contentFiles\lib\net472\Csla.xml"/>`

Please check [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#package-folder-structure), the sub node under contentFiles should be a codelanguage file type, like `cs`,`vb`, however, `lib` is not a member of these.

**And** if you are not sure of the codelanguage of the file, you can use generics, `any`, this is a large scope which works for all files.

**Instead**, use these under `nuspec` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    .......
<contentFiles>
<files include="any\net472\*.*" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true"/>
</contentFiles>
  </metadata>

<files>
<file src=".bin\net472\Csla.xml" target="contentFiles\any\net472\Csla.xml"/>
</files>
</package>
```

**Then**, repack your project, when you install this new version, please first [clean nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or just delete all cache files under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages`.